# When and Why to Use Custom Event Handlers

Tags: c#, wpf, events, delegates, event-handling

I have an object (actually a visual element and a viewmodel element) which I'd like to use in multiple places throughout my project. The function of the object is to collect payment information. Customer Smith ordered a Widget from my company, but he's late with the payment. He calls me to say that he'll pay the amount in full on the 1st. I fill in the payment amount and date, click a button, and an entry is added to my database with Mr. Smith's proposed payment info.

Now, as I said, I want to use this object in multiple places, and depending on where I'm using it, I may want more to happen after clicking the submit button. Along with Widgets, I also sell Whatsits and Whoozits. After receiving payment info for a Whatsit, I want to populate an additional table which will send the customer a reminder. After entering Whoozit payment info, I want to populate the reminder table, as well immediately sending the customer an SMS confirmation.

My original idea was simply to add a `List<Action>` field to my original object, and depending on where I'm accessing it from, send it any additional actions I want done after the original database update is complete.

Something like this:

```
public class MoneyGetter
{
    public List<Action> AfterEvents = new List<Action>();

    public void SavePaymentInfo()
    {
        //logic for initial database entry

        foreach(var a in AfterEvents)
        {
            a.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And after creating the object, depending on where I'm using it, I'd simply add

```
var mg = new MoneyGetter();
mg.AfterEvents.Add(() => { /* add situation specific action logic here */ });
```

After getting through some of this, it occurred to me that this is what events are for (I think), and I should be maybe creating a custom OnSubmitted event for my MoneyGetter object, subscribing to that event from whatever object is using it, and raising the event after the initial DB entry.

Is that the case? And if so, why is going through the trouble of creating a custom event handler a better idea than just having a `List<Action>`?

Comment: You don't need to, you can always make just custom args that extends from EventArgs, and use buildIn handler

Comment: Do you happen to use MVVMlight? There's a Messenger built-in.

Comment: Yes, events are supposed to be useful in this scenario.  There is no compelling reason I see that it needs to be a custom event.  You probably got into that mind-set because you focused too much on "add".  Events already do this by themselves, all you need is the += operator to subscribe the event.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that the case?

Probably, yes. If you want to be able to notify any subscribers when something happens in your class, raising an event is a common and good approach.

> And if so, why is going through the trouble of creating a custom event handler a better idea than just having a `List<Action>`?

Well, adding `Action<T>`s to a public `List<T>` is kind of a convoluted way to implement events. But I guess it would actually work. As a consumer of your class, I would expcect to be able to subscribe to an event using the `+=` syntax though instead of having to add/remove actions from a publicly exposed `List<T>`.

Comment: I am confused about that last sentence. I understand the intent of having such an Action-List to be that these Actions are performed when the event happens. So if he for examples has a public method with which registrees can put Actions to the list, it would make for a simple registration of callbacks. In that sense, you *can* "subscribe" to that list, actually.

Comment: What do you mean? How is the subscriber supposed to be notified when you add an action to a list?

Comment: He's not suppused to be notified of that. The subscriber does add an action. In the OP the List is even public. So any client could simply do `moneyGetterInstance.AfterEvents.Add( MyAction );`

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, that's kind of a convoluted way to implement events. But I guess it works. As  a consumer of your class, I would expcect to be able to subscribe to an event though instead of having to add/remove actions from a public List<T> property though.

Comment: I also don't get why OP thinks this is "easier" than using events ... And I myself would prefer events over such a list.

Comment: I just thought, I'd clear that out, so you can correct your answer.

Comment: @Fildor Maybe I'm just making events more complicated than they need to be, as I've never created one of my own.

Comment: It should be pretty easy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What about the event aggregator pattern? I use this quite frequently when my viewmodels need to communicate between each other.

Caliburn.Micro has a light-weight one built in that you could use. If you use an IoC container then its a snap to ensure every object can get a reference to the event aggregator and communicate freely.

> The Event Aggregator
>
> Caliburn.Micro comes pre-bundled with an Event Aggregator,
>   conveniently called EventAggregator. For those unfamiliar, an Event
>   Aggregator is a service that provides the ability to publish an object
>   from one entity to another in a loosely based fashion. Event
>   Aggregator is actually a pattern and it's implementation can vary from
>   framework to framework. For Caliburn.Micro we focused on making our
>   Event Aggregator implementation simple to use without sacrificing
>   features or flexibility. Getting Started
>
> As previously mentioned we provide an implementation of Event
>   Aggregator for you. This implementation implements the
>   IEventAggregator interface, however, you can provide your own
>   implementation if required. Please take a moment to familiarize
>   yourself with the IEventAggregator signature.
>
> ```
> public interface IEventAggregator {
>   bool HandlerExistsFor(Type messageType);
>   void Subscribe(object subscriber);
>   void Unsubscribe(object subscriber);
>   void Publish(object message, Action<Action> marshal);
> }
> ```

Info from: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator